# What glass shape is most commonly used for Saison's?

Tags: glassware, saison

Is there a widely accepted glass shape/type for Saison's (and if so, what is it)? Is a different glass used for French Saison's vs. Belgian Saison's vs. other common Saison styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there is a commonly accepted glassware for saisons in general.  [Different](http://fermentationriot.com/beerglasses.php?beerglass=Saison%20/%20Farmhouse%20Ale) sources [point](http://beeradvocate.com/beer/101/glassware/) to 3 different types: the pint, the tupic, and the oversized wine (goblet?).  A prticular saison may be better suited to one of those three, depending on whether it was crafted to have more or less aromatic, or just a beer for simple drinking.